# Difficulty adding multiple classes wit ng-class

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to add two classes to this div using `ng-class`, but even though `checkForActive` is returning `true`, it's being ignored and only `class_{{$index}}` is getting added.

If I remove `class_{{$index}}` altogether, `active` is added correctly.

Is there an obvious mistake in my syntax here?

```
<div "ng-class="{active: checkForActive, disabled: checkForDisable, class_{{$index}}} "></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just provide `true` value to the key `class_{{$index}}` just to that property gets added as a class name to the class list of the element. It is just the way you do `active: checkForActive`.

i.e

```
{active: checkForActive, disabled: checkForDisable, class_{{$index}} :true}
```

But i believe there could be some undesired behavior due the usage of interpolation (`{{`) within the ng-class directive (Atleast used to happen with older versions). So you could as well use an array.

```
ng-class="[checkForActive && 'active' , checkForDisable && 'disabled', 'class_' + $index]"
```

The above method will add a class name `false` if active or disabled is false, which should be harmless.

Or pass index to a controller function say `getStatus($index)` and return the object from there and use it in the ng-Class directive.

```
 $scope.getClass = function(){
     var obj = {active: $scope.checkForActive, disabled: $scope.checkForDisable}; 
     obj['class_' + this.$index] = true;
     return obj;
 }
```

and

```
 ng-class="getClass()"
```

[@Okazari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31054239/difficulty-adding-multiple-classes-wit-ng-class/31054525#comment50132011_31054525) pointed out that it indeed works by mixing `class` with  `ng-class` so you could also do:

```
class="class_{{$index}}" ng-class="{active: checkForActive, disabled: checkForDisable}"
```

Comment: This is a very helpful answer, much appreciated.

Comment: @Okazari It would work atleast in the first digest cycle. But if i remember correctly, ng-class watch will be set on derived value ex: `class_1` instead of `class_{{$index}}` (atleast with very old versions probably with 1.2). So if you remove or add an item it wont change. But not sure if this issue is no more with newer versions of angular though.

Comment: @Okazari Sorry above comment was based on `ng-class=".."` just saw you are asking about `class=".."` which would work as well but you cannot mix it with `ng-class` which provides a lot of flexibility.

Comment: Just made a tiny plunker about this http://plnkr.co/edit/Mi0EGvsqze6B8kwENL2d?p=preview looks like all is working fine. If i remember well using ng-class will just add classes into the class property of the element in addition to the already placed class.

Comment: @Okazari  Thanks for the plnkr.. Interseting. Probably angular version. Because i remember when i upgraded to 1.3.x in one of my applications i had this issue where while using interpolation inside a class ng-class was failing later while debugging i had found out that it is the ng-class that was the culprit and a similar error was logged in git as well. And that does not happen for simple scenarios, i had a bit of complex scenario in my application.